# movies that are favorites and the number of movies that are not

Tags: xml, python-3.x, counting

I need to find the number of movies that are favorites and the number of
movies that are not. In the XML doc, I can't get it to read this line `<movie favorite="False` to give me what I need.

**found this on the internet but it's not working**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
count = len(xml.findall(".//*[context='False']"))

**the other method that I tried**

for e in xml.findall(".//sub[context]"):
                if e.find("context").text in ('movie favorite', 'False'):
                    count += 1
                    print(count)
```

**My XML document looks like the following**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title=" Indiana Jones: The raiders of the Lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
```

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select tags in an `XML` document matching a given `XPath` expression. The `XPath` expressions supported by the `xml.etree` library are described here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath.

Having a look at the documentation I came out with this simple `XPath` expressions that does what you ask for: selecting all subelements of the root which are of kind `movie` and have the value for the attribute `favorite` set to `False`.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as Et
et.fromstring(xml)
e.findall('.//movie[@favorite="False"]')
[<Element 'movie' at 0x000001F20A6C48B8>, ...]
```

Comment: this is just a piece of my XML file that I copied (Top part) its closed in the original file

Answer (score 0):

I have only started learning xml and python but believe below would work?

```
favorite=[]
not_favorite = []

for movie in root.findall(".genre/decade/movie/[@favorite='True']"):
    fav = favorite.append(movie.attrib)
for movie in root.findall(".genre/decade/movie/[@favorite='False']"):
    non_fav = not_favorite.append(movie.attrib)
print(f"Number of movie favourites is {(len(favorite))}.")
print(f"Number of movie non favourites is {(len(not_favorite))}.")
```